# Adaptar aplicacion escritorio Java a cualquier pantalla

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenos dias,

estoy desarrollando una app de escritorio muy sencilla para testear unas pantallas tactiles.

LA cosa es que quiero una app con 4 botones que se adapten a todas las pantallas y que salga maximizada al ejecutarse.

Algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los rectangulos son los 4 botones y el circulo seria una imagen

Hay alguna manera de dejar fijo el logo y que los botones se expandan o se empequeñezcan dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla?

```
package javaapplication5;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication5 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame v=new JFrame();
        v.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();


        JButton btn1=new JButton("Boton 1");
        JButton btn2=new JButton("Boton 2");
        JButton btn3=new JButton("Boton 3");
        JButton btn4=new JButton("Boton 4");
        panel.add(btn1);
        panel.add(btn2);
        panel.add(btn3);
        panel.add(btn4); 




        v.add(panel);

        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);






        v.setVisible(true);


         int altoPanel=v.getBounds().getSize().height/2;
         int anchoPanel=v.getBounds().getSize().width;

         int alto=v.getBounds().getSize().height/2;
         int ancho=v.getBounds().getSize().width/2;


            //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(anchoPanel,altoPanel ));

            //tamaño a los botones=1/4 de pantalla

        btn1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ancho, alto));
        btn2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ancho, alto));
        btn3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ancho, alto));
        btn4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ancho, alto));
    }

}
```

Comment: donde puedo aplicarle tamaños por porcentaje?y alguna manera de dejar fijado el lateral del boton para que no se mueva del borde?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11570414/3850595

Comment: Hola Jordi, si el fullscreen sin problema, la cosa es hacer que los botones se adapten, es decir que de manera dinamica tengan un tamaño u otro sin depender de la pantalla

Comment: Hola Sergio. ¿Podrías poner la parte del código relevante que ya tienes?

Comment: entonces simplemente posiciona relativamente http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867167/java-swing-relative-positioning-and-automatic-resizing

Comment: He añadido el codigo que tengo hasta ahora...ya me direis si se os ocurre algo

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar un border layout para lo que necesitas, no pones nada en la parte superior ni inferior y colocas dos botones en el lado izquierdo y derecho en el centro tu imagen.

https://inforux.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/java-practicando-con-borderlayout/ aquí viene un ejemplo.

Comment: Lo que muestra el enlace que dejaste es para anchar el JFrame sin mas o apartir de ahi se puede aumentar el tamaño de los Botones que @SergioCV menciona?